# Border around tableheaders

Tags: visualforce

Updating an existing visualforce pdf output.  The report lists dozens of pageBlockTables, and they all work fine, except that the HeaderValues don't have borders.  The data does, but not the header row.

```
        <p class="TableHeader">Audited Financials and Operating Data</p>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!finFilings}" var="fFile" >
                <apex:column style="border:1px solid black" value="{!fFile.Filing_Name__c}" HeaderValue="Year"/>
                <apex:column style="border:1px solid black" value="{!fFile.Date_Required__c}" HeaderValue="Date Required"/>
                <apex:column style="border:1px solid black" value="{!fFile.Date_Financials_Filed__c}" HeaderValue="Date Financials Filed"/>
                <apex:column style="border:1px solid black" value="{!fFile.Finding__c}" HeaderValue="Finding"/>
                <apex:column style="border:1px solid black" value="{!fFile.Date_Op_Data_Filed__c}" HeaderValue="Date Op Data Filed"/>
                <apex:column style="border:1px solid black" value="{!fFile.Op_Data_Status__c}" HeaderValue="Finding"/>                    
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
```

I've tried to add a border rule everywhere but it won't put a border on the header row.  What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code

```
style {        
            border:0.8px solid black;
    }

    th {
           border:0.8px solid black;
    }

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!finFilings}" var="fFile" styleClass="style " />
```

or try adding border attribute to apex:pageblocktable

Answer (score 2):

put this in your page head tag

```
    <style>
        .mikoclass
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
```

put this in your pageblock tag

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable headerClass="mikoclass">
```

Comment: Thank you, completely spaced on the syntax:

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!finFilings}" var="fFile" border="1px solid black">

Works perfectly.